# Encrypting a password column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database table that looks like this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE  User 
(
     ID int, 
     UserName varchar(100), 
     password varchar(100), 
     primary key (ID)
)
```

I want to encrypt the `password` column. I have looked into TDS (Transparent Data Encryption) and it appears that you can encrypt databases and columns at the file level.

**If I use this approach then will people see the password if they run the following query:**

```
select password from [User]
```

The database runs on SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: The usual approach is to store a salted hash of the password...

Comment: The whole concept here is wrong and bad for security. Never store a password with encryption, use a salted hash instead, as @MartinMilan suggests.

Answer (score 4):

You could take a look at this [link](https://chandradev819.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-password-in-asp-net-using-c/) which could get you started in the right direction.

That being said however, it is the usual practice to store the hash value of the password itself rather than an encrypted version of the password. The hashing will allow you to check if the user has entered the correct password (by comparing the hash value you have in your database with the hash value of whatever the user entered) without the need of knowing what is the actual password.

The advantage of this is that it is usually simpler and more secure since you do not need to encrypt/decrypt any values. The drawback of using hashing is that you can never send the users their passwords (if you are planning to provide some sort of 'forgot my password' functionality) but rather you will have to reset it to a new, random one.

```
public string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        if (plainText == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");

        //encrypt data
        var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
        byte[] encrypted = ProtectedData.Protect(data, null, Scope);

        //return as base64 string
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }


public string Decrypt(string cipher)
    {
        if (cipher == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("cipher");

        //parse base64 string
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(cipher);

        //decrypt data
        byte[] decrypted = ProtectedData.Unprotect(data, null, Scope);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decrypted);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks +1.  Would this approach work if I had a table called Database containing connection information for thirty databases (I would want to encrypt the password column).

Comment: updating my answer :)

Comment: If a user has forgotten their password, you don't send them their old one.

Comment: Yes old password sending is a bad practice

Comment: Given that the question is not tagged with c# it seems unlikely the OP is actually asking how they can encrypt data without TDE in SQL Server, using c#. Additionally, as stated, the idea of encrypting a password is actually misguided.

Comment: question is incomplete so I just point at a way to encrypting

Answer (score 1):

You may also take a look at this [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/) which demonstrates the use of symmetric key encryption.

Comment: (Y) check this one too

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE [Users] (
    UserID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    [Login] varchar(32) unique,
    [Email] varchar(32) unique,
    [Password] varbinary(256) not null,
    [BackupCode] varbinary(256) not null,
    ModifiedDate datetime default (getdate()));

DECLARE @EncryptionKey nvarchar(32) = '007London' ;
DECLARE @Password varchar(32) = 'LoveDanger&Romance' ;
DECLARE @Code varchar(32) = 'GoNawazGo' ;
```

Insert Query(encryption):

```
INSERT [Users] ([Login], [Email], [Password], [BackupCode])
SELECT 'JamesBond', 'test@test.com',
    EncryptByPassPhrase(@EncryptionKey, @Password),
    EncryptByPassPhrase(@EncryptionKey, @Code)
```

Select Query(decryption):

```
 SELECT *, 
     DecryptedPassword = Convert(varchar(32),
     DecryptByPassPhrase(@EncryptionKey, [Password])),
     [Password],
     DecryptedCode = Convert(varchar(32),
     DecryptByPassPhrase(@EncryptionKey, [BackupCode])),
     [BackupCode]
     FROM [Users]
```